# C++ How to delete a default object member which is a pointer

Tags: c++, oop, delete-operator

I have a type which has as a member a pointer to another object. When the object (Demo) is created, it initializes the other object (Property) in the constructor. I figure if I have a lot of these objects, I wouldn't want to waste heap space when I change property to something differently, so I free the initialized memory in `setProperty`, then in the Demo's deconstrucor I delete it again, since it will have been set to something different by that point. However, this causes the code to crash. Why does it crash if I'm reassigning `property` when it is reset?

```
class Property{ };


class Demo{
    protected:
            Property *property;
    public:
            Demo(){ property = new Property();};

            void setProperty(Property *p){
                    delete property;
                    property = p;
            };

            ~Demo(){
                    delete property;
            };
};

int main(){
    Property p = Property();
    Demo * d = new Demo();

    d->setProperty(&p);

    delete d;
}
```

Comment: Where is `property` even declared? Also, you only use `delete` to free things created with `new`. `p` in `main()` is stack-allocated, so `Demo::~Demo()` is effectively deleting a stack-allocated object, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Besides the fact that this doesn't even compile (`property` doesn't exist), there are so many misconceptions here I don't even know where to begin. Why are you using dynamic allocation in the first place, pray tell?

Comment: You're violating the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), and you're trying to delete an object that wasn't allocated with `new`.

Comment: I realized that I forgot the protected Property *property;

Comment: You aren't allowed to `delete` objects that weren't created with `new`. That explains the crash.

Answer (score 5):

You pass address of object not created by `new` and then try to `delete` it. This is undefined behaviour.

The most probable crash course explantion is that standard library also frees `Property p`. You free it first, then at the end of the program it again frees `p`.

The possible "fix" is to pass an object that is allowed to be deleted, i.e. created by `new`.

```
int main(){
    Property *p = new Property();
    Demo * d = new Demo();

    d->setProperty(p); // Demo is responsible for freeing `p`.

    delete d;
} // standard libraries do clean up objects from `main` here
```

Please note that there are better and cleaner ways of implementing what you are trying to do. This answer just explains the crash.

You should see this, that is pretty hard with this desing to chose whether you should free or not. So your code depends on parameter origin. That should be a red-flag for design.

Answer (score 3):

Eliminate all memory management woes by using the appropriate tools provided by the standard library.

```
#include <memory>

class Property{ };


class Demo{
    protected:
            std::unique_ptr<Property> property;
    public:
            Demo()
            : property { new Property() }
            { }

            void setProperty(std::unique_ptr<Property> p){
                property = std::move(p);
            };

    // un-necessary
    //        ~Demo(){
    //                delete property;
    //        };
};

int main(){
    auto p = std::unique_ptr<Property>(new Property);  // or in c++14: = std::make_unique<Property>();
    auto d = std::unique_ptr<Demo>(new Demo); // or in c++14: = std::make_unique<Demo>();

    d->setProperty(std::move(p));

    // no longer necessary
    // delete d;
}
```